# iPhone RPG scrolling text for dialogue

Tags: iphone, text, scroll

I have an RPG in development, but I'm still confused about the best way to display dialogue.

I want there to be a text box with text that scrolls (like any RPG), but what is the best way to accomplish this using X-Code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `UITextView` and the `scrollRangeToVisible` method. As you browse methods don't forget it inherits from `UIScrollView` (so you can use `UIScrollViewDelegate` too) which has some really useful methods related to movement.

You could probably use just one `UITextView` in your app and manipulate the text/scrolling position as necessary. Using conventional animation all kinds of fades and effects are possible.

If you need colored text with various fonts you need to use `UIWebView` which does not inherit from `UIScrollView` but `UIView` - so your animation approach would be based more on familiar things you can do to a `UIView` but still not hard.

Don't forget to use that classic piece of RPG dialog, "..." - but please don't make text appear slowly, character by character, or have long un-skippable animations - going through the introduction of Final Fantasy Tactics Advance for the second time nearly killed me.

Comment: I found this bit of code:
UITextView * tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 100)];
 self.textView = tv;
 [tv release];
 [self.view addSubview:textView];
 [textView setText:@"What the hell\nis going on?\nla\nla\nla"];
 [textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([textView.text length]-1, 1)];

However, I'm still very confused about how to get the text to magically horizontally appear like it does in every other RPG. Mind giving me a few pointers? Thanks!

Comment: What I mean is: The dialogue box would start out blank, and the text would be "revealed", like it is in most JRPGs. Can that be accomplished with a TextBox? Thanks!

Comment: Yes - set a timer to fire at the frequency you want characters to appear, on each timer event add one character to textView.text - but don't forget you can't touch UIKit in a secondary thread and don't forget to allow aborting the gradual reveal for people who have sat through it all once already.

Comment: Do you mean I would be concatenating a string-character on each fired timer event?